# How to get SSO authentication working with tomcat on Linux

Tags: authentication, tomcat, single-sign-on

I'm struggling with this for a while. I've seen several ways to get SSO working with tomcat but wasn't able to get this working. Is there a recommended module for this?

Comment: What version of Tomcat? What SSO do you need? Between WAR on the same Tomcat?

Comment: Tomcat version 7.0. We'd like to be able to authenticate users from Windows Active Directory.